# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flipper-Folly"

Tags: react-native, podfile

I have been trying to run ios for a new but kept getting this error

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/struggle/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/client-grabnjjdhfcfyugfdqcwdvbebnva/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/struggle/Desktop/Tax/client/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I saw a solution that said to add `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })` in my podfile now when i run pod install i get the following error

```
`[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flipper-Folly":

In Podfile:
Flipper-Folly (= 2.3.0)

FlipperKit (~> 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
  FlipperKit/Core (= 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
    Flipper (~> 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
      Flipper-Folly (~> 2.2)

FlipperKit (~> 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
  FlipperKit/Core (= 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
    Flipper (~> 0.54.0) was resolved to 0.54.0, which depends on
      Flipper-RSocket (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
        Flipper-Folly (~> 2.5)`
```

Using `({'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0'})` results in me getting the inital error again.
Please help me fix this issue. Thank You

Answer (score 48):

In my case, I had just had to update the repo.

`pod install --repo-update`

the above command worked for me.

Comment: From the command output: out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.

Comment: same error, made no difference

Answer (score 24):

Delete Podfile.lock and run pod install. It will start working.Also update your cocoapods by running sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Don't do it never! Lock file needed for specify your packages versions.

Comment: You can safely do it. As pod install will generate a new, updated version of the Podfile.lock.
It's like a ios version of rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Answer (score 15):

as of today April 11, 2021 `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })` no longer works. Instead you use, `use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5' })` if this won't work in the future either. Look into the error it will tell you which version to use.

Answer (score 7):

For Mac M1 mates.

I just updates the repo.

> arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

its worked

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved the issue by running this command!

> pod update RCT-Folly --no-repo-update

Answer (score 4):

Remove the version with flipper so that it installs the latest available one on pod install.

So in pod file:

Change:

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })
```

to:

```
use_flipper!
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete Podfile.lock
2. Add to your Podfile

   use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' }) # update this part
   post_install do |installer|

   flipper_post_install(installer)

   end
3. run pod install.

if your Podfile contains below code or something like this and its working successfully for one of your project but not working for others,
which means

Your podfile.lock may contains above definition or working flavour of folly.

```
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

after running above command for the issue on M1 Chip Mac

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FlipperKit": In
> Podfile: FlipperKit (= 0.125.0)

and you will see the result as per showing image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For xcode 13 and react-native 0.66 (since the question is tagged with react-native), the only solution that worked for me is:

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
 rm -rf node_modules/
 rm -rf package-lock.json 
 cd ios && pod deintegrate
 cd .. && rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock 
 npm install
 npm audit fix
 react-native link
 cd ios && pod install
 cd .. && react-native run-ios
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28408

Answer (score 0):

I needed to go down one version before it, since the last one was 3 hours ago and obviously still not available in any repo.

Check this:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases
And this:
https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022, May 27th:

```
npx pod-install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

version '2.6.10' works for me

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.10' })
```

Answer (score -1):

For fast fix

Do update pod file :-

```
# use_flipper!
# post_install do |installer|
# flipper_post_install(installer)
# end
```